# Нахождение многопоточных проблем

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

У меня снова глупый вопрос про многопоточность. Как известно многопоточный код чреват многими ошибками которые не актуальны при однопоточном программировании. К тому же они весьма трудно уловимы. Часто бывает трудно искусственно смоделировать какой-либо баг который то появляется то исчезает при работе приложения потому что сложно предсказать как именно и когда именно два разных потока обратятся к данным так что это приведет к порче данных. К тому же у меня наверное еще не очень хорошо развито умение выискивать проблемные с точки зрения многопоточности места в коде. А теперь вопрос: есть ли какие-то рецепты как обнаруживать потенциальные проблемы многопоточного доступа к данным? Вот например блокировки lock. Есть ли какие-то верные признаки по которым можно было бы сказать что вот в этом коде использующем многопоточность нужен lock а вот тут не нужен? Особенно с учетом того что баги связанные с использованием потоков часто бывает трудно отловить? Как вообще локализуются такие проблемы при написании кода и как они отлавливаются при дебаге?

Comment: Одновременное чтение и запись одних и тех же данных из разных потоков однозначно требуют синхронизации.

Comment: Очень просто. Используете переменную из разных потоков — lock нужен. Не используете — не нужен.

Comment: Единственное исключение — локальные переменные в async-методах. Несмотря на то, что части async-метода могут выполняться в разных потоках, синхронизация выполняется автоматически.

Comment: Находить проблемы с многопоточностью примерно так же трудно, как читать текст без пунктуации.

Comment: Если вам дали исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первое правило многопоточности - не используйте многопоточность :)

Блокировки и прочие види синхронизации нужны для разделения доступа к *ресурсам* из разных потоков. Использование одного и того же объекта (не класса, а именно объекта) всегда требует явной или неявной блокировки/синхронизации.

Потенциально проблемные места:

- Явная статика
- Неявная статика (использование Singleton в коде, любые вызовы вида SomeClass.Instance)
- Явные (параметрами) или неявные (через замыкания) переданные в фоновые потоке объекты.

Основные принципы починки проблемных мест:

- Переход на классы, явно поддерживающие многопоточность. Например, проблема из [вашего соседнего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491777/) решается заменой линейного поиска перебором `List<DownloadTask>` на поиск по ключу в `ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, DownloadTask>`
- Ревью кода с точки зрения "предполагать что на каждом шаге другой поток обяхательно возьмет и все поменяет". Расстановка локов для предотвращения таких ситуаций.
- В случае проблем с многопоточностью при хранении данных - перекладываение проблем многопоточности из кода C# на сторонние системы (базу данных, очереди сообщений, nosql, кэш).

Answer (score -2):

> многопоточный код чреват многими ошибками которые не актуальны при однопоточном программировании.

Никаких ошибок не будет, если писать правильно.
Покамест в вашем коде нет объектов, которые могут меняться из разных потоков, то такое ни чем не чревато.

Попробуйте ради интереса создать множество потоков, которые просто читают значение свойства в объекте следующего класса

```
public class Mein 
{ 
    private int _Kalkulation;

    public Mein(int kalkulation) 
    {
       _Kalkulation = kalkulation;
    }
    public int Kalkulation
    {
       get 
       {
          return _Kalkulation;
       }
    }
}
```

Никогда не будет проблем с таким объектом, сколько бы потоков его не читали.  Но, как только вы позволите менять значение свойства из разных потоков, то проблемы обязательно когда-нибудь дадут о себе знать, в виде неожиданных значений. Однозначно требуется синхронизация, если доступ происходит из разных потоков.

Пример: счет в банке, который могут менять разные потоки. Например, по ордеру надо списать 100 единиц со счета. Поток проверяет количество единиц на счете, получает значение 120, и пока он выполняет какой-то расчет, другой поток снимает 100 со счета и первый поток также снимает 100. Такое очень чревато и нафиг никому не нужно, как вы понимаете.

Comment: _Никаких ошибок не будет, если писать правильно_. Это относится к любой теме в программировании.

Comment: Просто с языка сняли. Тоже хотел покапитанить, но не стал. Не надо забывать, что мы программисты зависим от железа, в котором тоже бывают ошибки.